# Check if object parameter contains list of letters

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I have a list of objects with parameters ID, and Code. I want to return the Objects that contain specific letters within the Code parameter.

```
ID   Code  
---------
0    ABCD  
1    LMNO  
2    ARDQ  
4    PQRD
```

List of string -> Letters = ('A','M','DQ')

For this example, it should return any objects that contain 'A' or 'M' within the Code parameter.

Results -> Object ID's 0,1,2

I tried something like this

```
var Results = MyObjects.FindAll(x => Letters.Contains(x.Code))
```

But this isn't what I want, I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: This is a problem that is too hard for you to solve. When you are in that situation, think: **is there a simpler problem that I can solve that gets me part of the way?**  Here's a simpler problem: **what are all the objects whose code contains "A"?** Can you solve that problem?  If not, well, you know what to do: **keep going**.  Find an even simpler problem that gets you part way there.  **What is the most complicated but simpler version of this problem that you can solve correctly**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The works given the update of the question from what was originally asked.

```
var Results = MyObjects.Where(x => letters.Any(y => x.Code.Contains(y))).Select(x => x.ID);
```

for each object, letters is checked to see if it is contained in the code.

Comment: sorry, I did not explain that well in my question.  The list of string is not char it could contain multiple letters.  I've edited my question to include an example where the list of letters contains 'DQ'.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this for a while, I think the best solution is a nested foreach.

```
var Results = New Object();
foreach(Object row in myObject)
{
    foreach(string letter in letters)
    {
        if(row.column2.contains(letter))
        {
            Results.add(row);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: it's my understanding that the Contains method cannot have a list of string as an input.  Only a list of Char.  There can be multiple letters that's it's trying to match to.